# What to include in an application Wiki?

Tags: documentation, confluence

What information would be best placed in a wiki?

This particular application is a rewrite from Classic ASP to ASP.Net Core.

I have gone over the deployment process, have made a walk through of the existing and new app via screenshots (the application has around 15 pages in total).

What else would help whoever picks this project up next?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is a bit unclear and broad, I can add points from my notes about which pages are typically required for almost any team:

- Sprints retrospective.
- Versions history: when do you do branching and releases.
- Production deployment state and history.
- Software used by team (Dev, QA, BA, whatever team members you have)
- Onboarding pages.
- Cheatsheets for commands (SQL scripts, git commands, bash commands etc.)
- Links to all resources (test servers, jira, wiki, CI servers etc.)
- Database schema pages.
- Glossary.
- Code conventions.
- Naming conventions (UI naming, how to write domain-specific terms etc.)
- Team list, contacts, roles and geographical position.
- Responsibility matrix: who is responsible for what project functionalities.
- Any hidden knowledges about the code.